# How split collection of validated objects in Spring and bean validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Consider:

```
@PostMapping("/track")
public void sendTopicCallback(@RequestBody @Validated Request request): CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>>
```

And `Request` is:

```
public class Request {
    @Valid
    private List<MyObjects> objects;
}
```

How to validate request but instead of returning 400 error code get valid object `List` and `List` of errors mapped with raw data?

Answer (score 0):

I am sitting in the train and have no PC with me, so I can just point you in a direction.

What happens in Spring internally, is that a `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown. This exception contains all violations found by the validator. This information can be used to calculate the information you need.

Second thing that happens when an exception is thrown by a `RestController` it is handled by an exception handler which maps it to an appropiate http response. If no handler is defined a default handler is used.

There are multiple ways to define such a handler, this is best explained in the official [documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

There you can define a handler for the `ConstraintViolationException` where you create your desired response.